# Handling Recursion and Error Cases in Nested List Length Calculation in python

Tags: algorithm, stack

I'm creating an improved version of the recursive function to calculate the length of a nested list that handles maximum recursion depth and potential error cases.

```
def recursive_list_length(items, depth=0):
    if not isinstance(items, list):
        return 1
    elif depth > 10:
        raise RecursionError("Maximum recursion depth exceeded")

    total_count = 0
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            try:
                total_count += recursive_list_length(item, depth + 1)
            except RecursionError as e:
                print(f"Recursion error occurred at depth {depth + 1}: {e}")
        else:
            total_count += 1
    return total_count
```

This code attempts to address the issues of excessive recursion and potential errors:

**Maximum Recursion Depth Handling:** It introduces a depth parameter to track the recursion depth and raises a `RecursionError` if the depth exceeds 10.

**Error Handling:** It attempts to handle potential `RecursionError` exceptions by printing an error message and returning 0 instead of propagating the error.

The code introduces additional complexity points compared to the simpler version and Setting a fixed maximum recursion depth of 10 might not be sufficient for arbitrarily deep nested.
So, Is there any alt way to traverse nested lists without relying on deep recursion, which can handle deep recursion and reduce the complexity?

Comment: OK, so what now? Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid errors from deep recursion, you must avoid recursion.

Think about how a computer actually works. Recursion creates an implicit stack of states. When you return, you are returning to a previous state, and continuing from where you are.

To lose recursion you must keep an explicit stack. For a complicated recursive function, you need to also figure out how to get back to the same point that you were at previously. But this is a simple recursive function. So getting rid of recursion is as easy as this:

```
def list_length (items):
    # Just works like a global variable. Now I don't need returns.
    total_length = 0
    # A stack of frames. Each frame contains an index and possible list.
    stack = [(0, items)]
    while 0 < len(stack):
        # Figure out the current state.
        i, these_items = stack.pop()
        # Do we need the equivalent of a recursive function?
        if isinstance(these_items, list):
            # Are we done with this list?
            if i < len(these_items):
                # When we come back to this "frame", we'll be on the next item.

                stack.append((i+1, these_items))
                # And our next loop iteration will be a "recursive" call.
                stack.append((0, these_items[i]))
        else:
            # Just an item. Because we already popped a "frame", we'll go back to the previous level of "recursion".
            total_length += 1
    # All done. Return the answer.
    return total_length
```

And that's how you do recursion without recursion. This is exactly how Python does it for you, except that it does it implicitly and its stack frames have more in them.